# Select all employees having high salary for each profession

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table. I want to select all employees in each profession with maximum salary.

[image]

I tried everything, but nothing seems to be working.
The below query results error.

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID IN (
SELECT EmployeeID FROM Employee  HAVING MAX(Salary) = Salary GROUP BY Profession)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Row_number()OVER (PARTITION BY Profession ORDER BY Salary DESC) rn
        FROM   Employee) a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Note : When there is a tie in maximum salary for a profession then this will return only one, if you need the tie records then use `DENSE_RANK`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Dense_rank()OVER (PARTITION BY Profession ORDER BY Salary DESC) rn
        FROM   Employee) a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

in case you want to fix your sub-query then(will return the tie records)

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employee e1
WHERE  Salary = (SELECT Max(Salary)
                 FROM   Employee e2
                 WHERE  e1.Profession = e2.Profession)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employee e1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   Employee e2
               WHERE  e1.Profession = e2.Profession
               HAVING Max(Salary) = e1.Salary)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
      SELECT * 
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Profession ORDER BY Salary DESC) rn 
      FROM Employee
      ) x
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple query !

```
SELECT 
       EmployeeID              ,
       EmployeeName            ,
       Profession              ,
       max(Salary)   AS 'Salary'
FROM 
       Employee
GROUP BY 
       Profession
```

Comment: This is simple and works _sort of_...  when two people in the same profession have the same, highest, salary only one is returned. The question asks for "..all employees in each profession with maximum salary"

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM employees 
WHERE salary IN (SELECT MAX(salary)
                 FROM Employees
                 GROUP BY Profession)
```

Comment: This query will not work correctly because it matches _any_ employee against a profession if their salary happens to match the `MAX` salary for that profession. It's not apparent in the data provided in the question but if the max salary of the Accountants was 4000, Salem the programmer would also appear in the results, along with programmer Jone.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.